# Limit queryset results based on model field, are there better ways?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-piston

basically i want to get the latest 30 log entries for every Host. Currently i'm doing this in django-piston.

```
def read(self,request):
    val={}
    for x in Host.objects.all():
        val[x.uuid_id]=DataLog.objects.filter(host=x).order_by('-time')[:30]           
    return val
```

Unfortunately this request takes way to long (currently 1s for about 10k database entries).
Are there more efficient ways to do this?

Harper

Comment: This is a common problem with no single query solution short of raw SQL. Look up "Top N GROUP BY" to find help with the SQL. When I needed the top N questions per category for my FAQ, I first wrote raw SQL, then after a code change decided to scrap the idea and just cache the result :)

Comment: How about keeping the last 30 rows for each host in a different table (e.g. LatestDataLog)? Using a signal when a datalog is created, save the datalog id in LatestDataLog & purge records for the host beyond 30 rows.

Comment: I think your title as badly choosen. I wuold have ask "How to get the first N entries by category"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL as a database backend and don't need cross database compatibility, you can use the [powerful window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html) that allow something like that :

Imagine your table looks like that :

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    i serial primary key,
    value integer not null,
    date timestamp,
    category text);
```

And you want the most recent value for each category. You will do :

```
SELECT
    first_value(i) over w,
    first_value(value) over w,
    first_value(date) over w
    category,
FROM x
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date DESC);
```

You can use such a query in django via the `raw` method on the query set manager :

```
ModelX.objects.raw("""SELECT DISTINCT ....... FROM x WINDOW w .....""")
```

To get the last N entries by category, the query is a little more complicated and involves a subquery :

```
SELECT i, value, date, category
FROM (SELECT
        i, value, date, category,
        row_number() over w
    FROM x
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date DESC)) AS subquery
WHERE subquery.row_number <= 30;
```

Seeing that, you could even make a view :

```
CREATE VIEW x_with_reverse_date_index AS
    (SELECT
        i, value, date, category,
        row_number() over w
    FROM x
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date DESC));
```

And create a django model that queries this view :

```
class ModelX(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    row_number = models.IntegerField("Row number when ordering by date desc")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'x_with_reverse_date_index'
```

and query it "normally" :

```
ModelX.objects.filter(category__in = ('catA','catB'), row_number__lte = 30)
ModelX.objects.filter(row_number = 29)
...
```

**Warning** : again, don't do this if you need a code that works on another database engine.